# How do you specify input channel for multiple mics in pyaudio?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I'm using pyaudio and I'm wondering if there is a way to specify which input channel I'm getting my mic data during playback. So i have speakers and two mics and I want to get each mic signal seperately. Both speakers and mics are using the same soundcard.

Thanks!

basic idea:

```
while data != ''
      stream.write(data)
      data = wavefile.readframes(chunk)
      data1 = stream.read(ch1_chunk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/?

Then you can do something like this:

```
import sounddevice as sd
myrec = sd.playrec(mydata, input_mapping=[2])
```

You can specify whatever list of input channels you want to grab.

If you use this in a script, don't forget to use `blocking=True`.

For more options have a look at the docs for `sd.playrec()`: http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/#sounddevice.playrec.